# How to add export button in pdf form?

Tags: forms, pdf, pdf-generation

I have form in pdf file on website. I would like to access button to export pdf form filled by the customer on website. 
How I can customize pdf file in this way?

Comment: This question is not about programming. Please read the [help]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a button in your PDF in Acrobat Pro, double click on it to open up the **Button Properties**, go to the **Actions** tab and select '**Submit a form**' from the **Select Action** drop-down. Then click **Add...** to configure your preferences for what the action will save and where.

More info is available here...
https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/setting-action-buttons-pdf-forms.html

Comment: thanks, it was very helpful. do you know if I can create drop-down list in pdf to select different options and based on different options appears various fields to be filled by customer?

Comment: PS: I have to notice that Acrobat Pro is not available for Linux, but this isnt a problem for me.

Comment: No problem. Your follow-up question is much bigger and more complicated. I would suggest that you could achieve this by using the display.hidden and display.visible syntax to show and hide the fields that are relevant to the particular choice from the drop down list. Try googling that.

Comment: I have one more thing yet. I would like to create order number (following or random) in header, which would create automatically for each different opening the file by customer. Can I achieve this by using mathrandom() or another function in JS?

Comment: You could use something like: var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1); This would give you a random number between 1 and 1000. Just change the 1000 to whatever you want the range to be and then format as required.

Comment: Can you please post any further questions as separate questions? This is turning into a conversation. Also, if you post each question as a new public question then more people will see them and you'll get better answers from people with more expertise than me. Thanks.

Comment: You are very helpful, thank you. 
I will have in mind your comments.

Comment: I have problem with button. This thing works correctly when I have file in disk and open this with AR. I need this on website, so, if I open this by browser - this functions doesn't works.

Comment: If your form is to be distributed on the internet then there are a few security issues that need addressing to allow it to save to a user's computer. You will need to create a custom save button with javascript. There is a good article with details here: https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/how-save-pdf-acrobat-javascript

Comment: Again, if you post this as a new question then you have a better chance of finding someone who knows more about this than me.